Find $(a-b)^3+(b-c)^3+(c-a)^3$ from $a+b+c=6$, $ab+bc+ca=11$ and $abc=6$
I first started simplifying the expression:
$$(a-b)^3+(b-c)^3+(c-a)^3=3(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$
I went one more step further and wrote the expression $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ as:
$$ab^2-a^2b+b^2c-bc^2+c^2a-ac^2$$
Now, what can I else do? I know that $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$ is a solution to this, but I do not want to use this values directly. I need to use the values of the three expression to evaluate this expression of the question. Is it really possible? I tried some of more steps I could:
$$ab^2-a^2b+b^2c-bc^2+c^2a-ac^2$$
$$=a^2b+ab^2+3abc+b^2c+bc^2+ac^2+a^2c-3abc-2(a^2b+bc^2+ac^2)$$
$$=ab(a+b+c)+bc(a+b+c)+ca(a+b+c)$$
But I am helpless again. Need some guidelines. Is it really solvable?

The constraints are symmetric in $a,b,c$ but the test function isn't.

@lulu isn't this the expression for $\sum{(a-b)^3}$?

A similar problem was recently posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4951292/42969

With the notation of this answer your expression is equal to $3(p-q)$ and $(p, q)$ can be $(25, 23)$ or $(23, 25)$. I suggest to close this question as a duplicate.

@MartinR Is there any symmetric expression that contains the terms $(a-b)^3$ and other permutations of $a$, $b$ and $c$? I would be pleased to know that...

The problem can't be solved uniquely, as I said.  The solutions are ${a,b,c}={1,2,3}$ in some order.  If you take the order $(1,2,3)$ you get $6$ for the test function,  if you take $(3,2,1)$ you get $-6$.  In any case, since it's easy to compute the values (up to order) you can certainly evaluate any symmetric function in them.

Setting $c=6-a-b$, the other two conditions have resultant $(b-1)(b-2)(b-3)=0$. Say $b=1$, then $a=2$ or $a=3$ etc. With $(a,b,c)=(2,1,3)$ we have $(a-b)^3+(b-c)^3+(c-a)^3=-6$. And similarly for the other cases.

The square of your expression can be written in terms of $6,11$ and $6$

It's clearly not a duplicate. I find this tendency to close questions because there are similarities to older questions to be counterproductive. Besides the fact there are differences in the questions, often the answers to the old question can be improved and I think it would often be helpful to keep the newer question active longer.

Well, I am not very experienced but one way is to brute force Vieta’s.
Assume a, b, c are roots of cubic equation p(x)
$a + b + c = 6$
$ab + bc + ca = 11$
$abc = 6$
So, $p(x) = x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6$
Then by factorisation,
$p(x) = (x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)$
So, it’s roots are 1, 2, 3.
suppose, $a = 1$, $b = 2$, $c = 3$
So, $3(a-b)(b-c)(c-a) = 3(-1)(-1)(2)$
$3(a-b)(b-c)(c-a) = 6$
Note: There may be some errors and if you do spot some please let me know. Also there are other answers arrived at through permutations of $(a,b,c)$. My main objective was showing a process.

Well your answer is partially correct but still $-6$ is also an answer...

You have just shown that ${a,b,c} = {1,2,3}$ but any permutation of $(1,2,3)$ will also work, and this leads to additional solutions.

@Zarrax which is why I mentioned there are other solutions

@Pradeep I just meant that those are all the solutions, so you are almost done.
